# How to: C++ Reading a File and using the "if statement"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from a file and check for words in the file, using the if statement, if there is a word in the file, I want it to output a certain text.

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone enlighten me? Please help rather than calling a me a moron or whatever. I want to learn, I'm a C++ and programming Noob.

Here's what's in the file text so far line by line:

Female8D

Male7E

Male8D

Female7B

```
void fourCoats() 
{
    string word;

    ifstream horseList;
    horseList.open("horseList.txt");
    if (!horseList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
        exit(1);
    }



    while (horseList >> word)
    {

        if (word == "Male8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Female7B") {
                    cout << "You have Male8D and Female7B.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Female8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Male7B") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male7B.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Male8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Female7C") {
                    cout << "You have Male8D and Female7C.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Female8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Male7C") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male7C.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Male8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Female7D") {
                    cout << "You have Male8D and Female7D.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Female8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Male7D") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male7D.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Male8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Female7E") {
                    cout << "You have Male8D and Female7E.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (word == "Female8D") {
            while (horseList >> word) {
                if (word == "Male7E") {
                    cout << "You have Female8D and Male7E.\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }


   horseList.close();

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your objective is, do you want to report all distinct words in the file? if that's the case look at std::set() and put the words into a set as you read them then iterate over the set to report them.

Comment: So basically I want to see if I have a certain combination of "horses" like Male8D and Female7E, the user inputs to the text file to save the horses that they have. 

If I have Male8D and Female7E, I want it to output "You have Male8D and Female7E."  If I have different combinations I want it to output that to the user.

The whole point of the program is to print out the best combinations first and then the worse combinations following after, or even just the best combinations if you have the required horse combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your control flow loop is not clear to identify the strings present in the file.
Assuming you want to print the strings as you find them you can use switch-case statements to and do your output accordingly.
Alternatively, you can assign an integer to each string and output your result.
For example,

```
if (word == "Male8d")
    count+ = 1
if (word == "Female8d")
    count+ = 2
```

And after that print the output according to your sum.

Comment: So the program works as this: 
1.The user inputs the horses they have
2.They can check what horses they have in their list
3.They use this function to see if they have a combination, it's supposed to be ordered from the most desired combination to the least desired combination.

Answer (score 0):

The program you provided can only print first two matches. The following one might work for all possible matches.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    set<string> matchs;
    // List of words to match
    const unordered_set<string> patterns = {"Female8D","Male7E","Male8D","Female7B"};

    ifstream horseList;
    horseList.open("horseList.txt");
    if (!horseList.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while(horseList>>word) {
            if(patterns.find(word)!=patterns.end()) {
                // record word if it matches
                matchs.emplace(word);
            }
        }
        cout << "You have ";
        for(auto ptr=matchs.begin(); ptr!=matchs.end(); ptr = next(ptr)) {
            // print matched words
            const string & w = *ptr;
            if(ptr==prev(matchs.end())) {
                cout << "and " << w << '.' << endl;
            } else {
                cout << w << ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First

```
ifstream horseList;
    horseList.open("horseList.txt");
    if (!horseList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
        exit(1);
    }
```

well,I have never seen that "exit",instead of exit() you could make fourCoats() a `bool` and:

```
ifstream horseList;
    horseList.open("horseList.txt");
    if (!horseList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file...";
        return false;
    }
```

Now about the word check, there are 2 ways I at least know.
First:

```
if (word.find("The word you are looking for") != std::string::npos){
    /*Some code*/
}
```

Second:
    to overload the "==" operator, how to do this:
        Right after the libraries you have include, the namespaces you are using and 
        structures/classes you have made write this code:

```
bool operator==(const std::string &str0, const std::string &str1){
    int length;
    if (str0.length() < str1.length())
        length = str1.length();
    else 
        length = str0.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (str0[i] != str1[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What the second way does actually, you are saying the "==" operator that if from both sides(left and right) there are strings, then for(the_length_of_the_bigger_string){compare each letter of the one with the letter on the same place of the other, if at least once the letters are not equal, then `return false;` else `return true;`}

`return` ends the function and sets a value to that function
`int SomeFunc() {/* code */ return 3;}`, will set `SomeFunc` at the time we called it to `3`
basically at this example will set it every time to 3 but you know what i mean
`return value_or_variable;` is like **end the function and function = value_or_variable**

If anyone knows a way to improve the overload, please, write it on the comments, I need it too